# What is a "safe terminal width" these days (2019)?

Tags: terminal, formatting, typography, plaintext

I'm planning on making a certain kind of plaintext-based manual/whatever, meaning it will be presented using a fixed-width font and a fixed number of characters per line. Now I'm wondering what a "safe" such "line width" (in number of characters) is these days.

My first thought is "80", but I have two concerns with that:

1. I vaguely remember that 80 isn't safe for e-mail, but has to be 78 for some reason.
2. 80 seems very narrow when there are extremely high-res screens/desktops everywhere. On the other hand, there are also a lot of small "mobile devices", and a major reason I'm using this "primitive" method of presentation over rich HTML or something else is that it's supposed to be easy to read and concise.

120 is what Windows uses by default for cmd.exe, which seems slightly more sane than 80. However, I'm very torn about this.

I'm trying to maximize the compatibility and easiness of reading this content. I'm trying to avoid any kind of problems that might arise from choosing a too narrow or too wide value.

Also, yes, I know that HTML/CSS have all kinds of features for limiting the width and whatnot. However, even e-mail with HTML seems to be very problematic, and CSS appears to still not exactly be mature in terms of typography features.

To make it clear: I'm not asking specifically about e-mail, specifically about web pages, or specifically about any kind of existing medium. I'm trying to make this "universal" so that it can be applied to "any device/platform", excluding only *extremely* old/obscure/exotic ones which do something really crazy.

You might say that I should be storing it in a database (which I am) and then generate the appropriate format on an on-demand basis, which I might well do, but there's also the "beauty factor" of the presentation of the text. I wish to retain some kind of control at least for the "main" format (plaintext), where I can be sure that the readers are reading it as I intended it, meaning purposedly limited line widths for improved readability and also for the visual beauty of the text content.